# How to run ASP.NET MVC with Angular project in VS Code?

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a CRUD application with ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio with Angular and want to run the complete project only with VS Code, not with Visual Studio. Any solution for this purpose?

Comment: If it's .net core then you can self host it. If .NET, then look for Cassini adapter. The keywords you need to search for is "how to host x application" where x is either .net or .net core. You will get hundreds of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(c#)** Open the the folder with your `.csproj` file in your VS Code.

1. `dotnet restore`
2. `dotnet run` or `dotnet  watch`

For more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run

**(angular)** Open the the folder with your `package.json` file in another VS Code instance (or the same and open a new terminal).

1. `npm install`
2. `ng serve`

For more: https://cli.angular.io/

You should have `angular cli` and `dotnet` installed on your machine.